# Interruptible(blocking) sleep on metro app: CreateEventEx for Interrupt (e.g. Ctrl + C) WaitForSingleObjectEx on that

Tags: c++, c, windows-runtime, sleep, interrupt

I'm trying to wait on interrupt like Ctrl + C, on metro App.

I'm able to get blocking sleep, with `WaitForSingleObjectEx(GetCurrentThread(), ms, TRUE)`. This will block current thread until 'ms' mSec. Though it is set Alertable, its not getting out of 'Sleep' if I press Ctrl + C.

So I'm trying to achieve, sleep untill 'ms' msec or if user press Ctrl + C, then just come out and continue with next statement. Not sure how can I create an event for interrupt(sigint event) or waitfor on interrupt.

Comment: You can catch CTRL-C in a console program with [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg this applies to Desktop apps only ... can't use in Metro mode.